# Join on multiple columns with condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

**Table1:**

```
col1        col2        col3        col4        col5        col6        col7        col8 
7865                                                                                abc
                                    7269                                            def
            8726                                                                    ghi
                                                                        986         jkl
                                                7689                                mno
                        8762                                                        pqr
                                                                                    stu
                        9698                                                        vwx
            3568                                                                    yz
```

**Table2:**

```
Scientific value         mapping_value
1                        8726
2                        9698
3                        3568
4                        986
5                        7269
```

I want to match "col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7" column values in Table1 with "mapping_value" column in Table2 and create a new column called "Scientific value" in Table1 which would have entries from "Scientific value" column in Table2.

**Output:**

```
col1        col2        col3        col4        col5        col6        col7        col8   Scientific value
7865                                                                                abc    
                                    7269                                            def    5
            8726                                                                    ghi    1
                                                                        986         jkl    4
                                                7689                                mno
                        8762                                                        pqr
                                                                                    stu
                        9698                                                        vwx    2
            3568                                                                    yz     3
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is only one of `col1` non-NULL in any row (or only one not an empty string)?

Answer (score 1):

You could make a judicious use of `COALESCE` here:

```
SELECT
    t1.col1,
    t1.col2,
    t1.col3,
    t1.col4,
    t1.col5,
    t1.col6,
    t1.col7,
    t1.col8,
    t2."Scientific value"
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2
    ON COALESCE(t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3, t1.col4, t1.col5, t1.col6, t1.col7, t1.col8) = TO_NUMBER(t2.mapping_value);
```

The logic here is to take the first non `NULL` column from each record in the first table, and to use that as the mapping value.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I receive `ORA-01722: invalid number`, datatype of `mapping value is NVARCHAR2` and `col1 to col8 is NUMBER`

Comment: @pc_pyr Then use `TO_NUBMER` on the mapping value to convert to numeric in the `ON` join condition.

Comment: I used `TO_NUMBER` on mapping value, but I get `ORA-01722:invalid number error` again

Comment: Then your data has some problems.  Decide whether this data is numeric or text, and then use that consitently throughout.

Answer (score 1):

Do a `LEFT JOIN`, use `IN` to match any of the table1 columns:

```
select t1.*, t2.scientific_value
from t1
left join t2 on t2.mapping_value in (t1.col1, t1.col2, t1.col3 ... t1.col7)
```